# Compressing string in Scala, how to do this immutably?

Tags: scala

I have a string "abbbbccdddd" and the function should return "a1b4c2d4".

This is what I have written in Scala.

## Iterative-version

```scala
def compress(str: String) = {
  val chars = List(str).flatten.map(_.toString) ++ List(null)
  var result: String = ""

  var lookBack: String = chars.head
  var occurance: Int = 0

  chars.foreach { c =>
    if (c != lookBack) {
      result = result + lookBack.toString + occurance
      occurance = 0
    }

    occurance = occurance + 1
    lookBack = c
  }

  result
}
```

## Recursive-version

```
def compress(str: String): String = {
  def compressHandler(str: String, lookBack: String, occurance: Int, result: String): String = {
    if(str.isEmpty) {
      result
    } else if(str.head.toString == lookBack) {
      compressHandler(str.drop(1), str.head.toString, occurance + 1, result)
    } else {
      compressHandler(str, str.head.toString, 0, result + lookBack + occurance)
    }
  }

  compressHandler(str + "0", str.head.toString, 0, "")
}
```

Scala — being a functional language should have much better solutions!

How to improve second (by somehow using map/reduce/fold) and how to do the first following concept of immutability (purely functional)?

Comment: You can use mutable vars or collections. It is not tabu. The most important things are simplicity and sufficient  speed. For speed you should not use head, tail and reverse for String in this task. For simplisity you can use simple counter var and index. In some tasks you should prefer FP, in some -- iterative, in some -- special functions. I advice you to see Scala Days with Martin Odersky for 2013 оr 2014 year

Comment: Scala days: Scala with style https://youtu.be/kkTFx3-duc8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take using foldLeft:

```
def compress(s: String) = {
    val a : List[(Char,Int)] = List()
    s.toCharArray.foldLeft(a)((acc, elem) => acc match {
        case Nil => (elem, 1) :: Nil
        case (a, b) :: tail =>
            if (a == elem) (elem, b + 1) :: tail else (elem, 1) :: acc
    }).reverse
    .map{ case (a, b) => a.toString + b }
    .mkString("")
}
```

*Note*: I have assumed that order matters. That is, `aabbbaa` will reduce to `a2b3a2`

Comment: Cool stuff! However we can desugar this and get rid of `._1` and `._2` but it seems perfect to me.

Comment: changed to get rid of `._1` and `._2`

Comment: Welcome to code review. This answer is an alternate solution which is fine on stackoverflow.com but is not a good answer on code review. A good answer may not contain any code at all, but it must contain at least one meaningful observation about the code posted in the the question. Code can be used as examples to support the observations about the posters code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest omitting the allocation of extra space. Try to start with:

```scala
object Solution:
  def compress(str: String): String =
    val (sb, _) = 
      Vector.range(0, str.size + 1).foldLeft(StringBuilder(), 0) { 
        case ((sb, occurance), i) =>
          if i == 0
            ???
          else if i == str.size
            ???
          else if str(i) == str(i - 1)
            ???
          else
            ???
      }
    sb.toString
```